# How to access WSGI file (Procfile)

Tags: python, django, heroku

[image]I can’t access wsgi in heroku Procfile

```
web:gunicorn Medical_Portal.Medical_Portal.wsgi
```

My files :

My wsgi file in `Medical_Portal/Medical_Portal/wsgi.py`

Comment: show your directory structure.

Comment: I just edited the question